# What's the most efficient way to transfer data/packets between native code and Java code in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-code, raw-sockets, inter-process-communicat

I'm going to write an Android App to read raw packet from native code with raw socket interface. My phone is rooted so my native code can access to the native code by using runtime.exec("su"). But I don't know how to efficient transfer packets between the native code and Java code. (In this case, the native code and Java code are running in different processes) Since my App must process the raw packets from the native code as efficient as possible, I need a "fast tunnel" between them. Any ideas or suggestions?

P.S. I have tired Android NDK, but in NDK, native code and Java code are running in the same process so the native code cannot have the root privilege to access raw socket.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: create an agent at native layer so that it can talk to your java activity via JNI. Then hook up the agent and your native service by using IPC (binder).

One issue: it is not convenient to pass complex data structure via JNI. So step back, why do you want to pass entire packets? Can you process the packets at native layer and submit the result (e.g., integers) only?

Comment: Using Binder between custom Native components is possible, but may be a bit tricky.  A pipe or unix socket interface might be conceptually simpler; though if one really cares to optimize shared memory is supported.